# Active tag on Bootstrap with Django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of links on my navbar on Bootstrap

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li ><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
  <li ><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
  <li ><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Say I am at the "Home" section, I want to add a `<li class="active">` text on Django.

My first instinct is to use the context variable for **views.py** and do something like

```
context = { 'section' : 'home' }
```

and then do the matching of the string

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li {% if section == 'home' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
  <li {% if section == 'about' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
  <li {% if section == 'contact' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

To me, this seems to violate DRY and so I'm asking the community if there is a sleeker way to represent this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034107/django-along-with-bootstrap-navbar-distiinguishing-link-to-current-page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer checking the URL in template:

```
<li {% if "/" == request.path %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
<li {% if 'mypage1' in request.path %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'my_page_1' %}">My Page 1</a></li>
```

Comment: seems like this is the only way to do it...no way to do so using a generic method in the `template.html` files.

Comment: Yes I don't like it either because there is a chance that the string your checking against appears in another URL and you get two active menu items (although it's not very likely). This is the best I could do until now :)

Comment: Is this really the **best** way? Seems like there should be a cleaner way somehow.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer isn't perfect and DRY.

```
<li {% if 'mypage1' in request.path %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'my_page_1' %}">My Page 1</a></li>
```

What if you change the URL, you'd have to change it here everytime. What if you forget to do it?

What if you have multiple urls with 'my_page_1' in URL, for example, "127.0.0.7/my_page_2/list/my_my_page_1". But we want only "127.0.0.7/my_my_page_1". In this case both the URLs would be active. We don't want that

You can check if the URL matches using `request.resolver_match.url_name` instead.

```
<li class="nav-item {% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'index' %}active{% endif %}">
```

or

```
{% with url_name=request.resolver_match.url_name %}
<li class="nav-item {% if url_name == 'index' %}active{% endif %}"
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}" >Home </a>
</li>

{% endwith %}
```